# React Router 4 - Different Layouts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I know this is been asked a few times, but nothing really seemed to apply to me.

I have this

App.js

```
<React.Fragment>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/members" component={MemberAreaComponent} />
    <Route exact path="/" component={NonMemberAreaComponent} />
    <Route component={NotFoundComponent} />
  </Switch> 
</React.Fragment >
```

In members area component I have

```
// other html above here  

<div className="main-area">
  <main>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/members/home" component={HomeComponent} />
    </Switch> 
  </main>
</div>
```

NonMemberAreaComponent

```
<div className="non-members-area-container">
  <Route path="/login" component={LoginComponent} />
  <Route path="/" component={NonMemberHomeComponent} />
</div>
```

When I try to do /Login I keep getting my "NotFoundComponent". I think it is "exact" what is messing everything up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second `Route` only matches when the path is *exactly* `/`. Remove the `exact` prop to make it active when `/` is just a part of the path.

```
<React.Fragment>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/members" component={MemberAreaComponent} />
    <Route path="/" component={NonMemberAreaComponent} />
    <Route component={NotFoundComponent} />
  </Switch> 
</React.Fragment>
```

Comment: I think I need an exact somewhere. Thinking in the NonMemberAreaComponent for the "/"?

Comment: I think so, I just needed to move the "exact" I guess.